# list index out of range for knapsack problem without repetition

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Problem introduction:

> You are given a set of bars of gold and your goal is to take as much gold as possible into
> your bag. There is just one copy of each bar and for each bar you can either take it or not
> (hence you cannot take a fraction of a bar).

Problem Description:

> Task. Given  gold bars, find the maximum weight of gold that fits into a bag of capacity .
>
> Input Format. The first line of the input contains the capacity  of a knapsack and the number  of bars of gold. The next line contains  integers 0, 1, . . . , −1 defining the weights of the bars of gold.
>
> Constraints. 1 ≤  ≤ 10⁴
> ; 1 ≤  ≤ 300; 0 ≤ 0, . . . , −1 ≤ 10⁵.
>
> Output Format. Output the maximum weight of gold that fits into a knapsack of capacity .

My code is as follows:

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def optimal_weight(W, w):
    # write your code here
    n = len(w)
    value = [[0] * (W+1) for i in range(n+1)]
    
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, W+1):
            value[i][j] = value[i-1][j]
            # does not check every single possible weight
            # must loop through all diagonally top left cells
            v = w[i-1] + value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]
            
            if v <= j:
                value[i][j] = max(v, value[i][j])
            
    return value[n][W]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    W, n, *w = list(map(int, input.split()))
    print(optimal_weight(W, w))
```

My solution worked for the sample test cases given, but was rejected for one of the test cases:

> Failed case #7/14: Wrong answer
> wrong output format: list index out of range
>  (Time used: 0.01/10.00, memory used: 11313152/2147483648.)

May I know what could have resulted in the error or if there is a better way to implement a DP solution to this problem?

Comment: The [en.wikipedia pseudocode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem) checks `j-w[k]` against 0.

Comment: That's the only index that I found which isn't properly bounded, I think it is in fact `j-w[i-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible cause in my opinion is this statement:

```py
v = w[i-1] + value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]
```

There aren't any constraints which dictate that `j-w[i-1]` will be a valid index. Just replace it with

```py
if j-w[i-1] >= 0:
    v = w[i-1] + value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question as you.But now I figure it out by doing these following.

change your code:
v = w[i-1] + value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]

to:

if j-w[i-1]>=0:
v=L[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+w[i-1]
else:
v=L[i-1][j]

try this and see what happens

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33088418)